# Continuous Surjection on Connected Space is Connected

Tags: general-topology

I am working on a proof where given a continuous surjection f:X$\to$Y, if X is connected then Y is connected. I am doing so by contraposition so I assumed Y was disconnected and am attempting to show X is disconnected.

By definition of disconnected, there exist open sets A' & B' in $\tau_Y$ such that A'$\cup$B'=Y and A'$\cap$B'=$\emptyset$. Since f is continuous, f$^{-1}$(A')=A & f$^{-1}$(B')=B are nonempty & in $\tau_X$. We wish to show A$\cup$B=X.

Since f(A$\cup$B)=f(A)$\cup$f(B) (by image of union) we have f(A$\cup$B)=A'$\cup$B' (by definition of A & B) which is equivalent to f(A$\cup$B)=Y and finally by surjection f(A$\cup$B)=f(X).

This is where I am stuck. How can I conclude that A$\cup$B=X?

Comment: Are you stuck on proving $A\cup B\subseteq X$ or $X\subseteq A\cup B$?

Comment: In order to show X is also disconnected I need to show A & B are disjoint (easy), open (easy), nonempty (easy), and that they span X (which is where I am stuck). To show that they span X I need to show that either A$\cup$B=X or that X$\subseteq$A$\cup$B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that $A\cup B=X$, we have to show that $A\cup B\subseteq X$ and that $X\subseteq A\cup B$.

To prove that $X\subseteq A\cup B$, we suppose $x\in X$ and prove that $x\in A\cup B$.

What does $x\in A\cup B$ mean? It means that $x\in A$ or $x\in B$,

which means that $x\in f^{-1}(A')$ or $x\in f^{-1}(B')$,

which means that $f(x)\in A'$ or $f(x)\in B'$,

which means that $f(x)\in A'\cup B'$,

which means that $f(x)\in Y$.

So the problem boils down to showing that $x\in X$ implies $f(x)\in Y$.

Comment: I guess my problem here comes from when we have an x$\in$X that gives us an undefined f(x). Can we conclude that the undefined f(x)$\in$Y? For example a function that takes a to a, b to b, c to c where X={a,b,c,d} and Y={a,b,c}. Since d$\in$X we should be able to conclude f(d)$\in$Y but f(d) is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Y=A\cup B$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ where $A,B$ are open in $Y$. Then $f^{-1}(A),f^{-1}(B)$ are open in $X$ due to continuouity of $f$ and $f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)=\emptyset$ and hence $f^{-1}(A)=\emptyset $ or $f^{-1}(B)=\emptyset $ which means that $Y\cap A=\emptyset$ or $Y\cap B=\emptyset$. So $Y$ is connected.

Comment: Our teacher never gave us this definition of connectedness. In order to use it in my proof I'd have to prove that it is logically equivalent to my current definition.

Comment: @Anonymous        $Y$ is connected iff for open $A,B$ this is true $Y=A\cup B$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$=>$Y\cap A=\emptyset$ or $Y\cap B=\emptyset$.See that the contraopposite of this is the definition of connectedness that you know.

Comment: Y is the space $\tau_Y$ is over. Necessarily, Y is nonempty. Therefore, your condition implies either A is empty or B is empty, or A or B is disjoint from Y. A and B are subsets of Y so they cannot be disjoint, and they cannot be empty as connected requires nonempty, disjoint, open sets whose union is the whole space. I don't see how those two are logically equivalent when one seems to contradict the other.

Comment: @Anonymous the one you know says when a set is not connedcted.mine says when a set is connected

Comment: That would explain why they are contradictory then. Sorry for the confusion!